# Swf Handler Error on Firefox c#

Tags: c#, flash, firefox

I have implemented an httphandler that loads swf from database and returns it to the context. It works fine, on chrome, ie and firefox on my maching with visual studio iis.

When it goes live, in IIS 7.0 it works on chrome, ie but not in firefox....(so strange). The only thing that i can think of is that something is wrong with IIS. Any thoughts?

Here is my code

```
HttpResponse response = context.Response;
response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
response.Clear();
response.BufferOutput = true;
byte[] content = myMessage.ObjectValue;      
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
context.Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had very strange behavior on my "localhost" server with Firefox for my ASP classic pages. In IE and Chrome it worked fine, also on another "localhost" server and it also showed in one test no problem on my production server. I finally found the cause of very strange behavior. Firefox had loaded the page twice! And after a long night I found the culprit. It was the "response.flush" statement. Once I took them out, it worked fine. This effect of firefox loading pages twice happened after I had updated my "localhost" PC to the latest Windows 10. Before, never such an effect. When I was searching the net for the problem, I found your posting and thought I should let you know. Try taking out response.flush from your code if you can and maybe it helps.